# Receiving a JSON response from a POST request

Tags: python, json, post, python-requests, response

Using a POST request, my goal is to receive an authorization code from a JSON response. However, the only response I'm getting is the HTML of the webpage I'm connecting to, not the desired JSON response.

```
import requests
from base64 import b64encode


appAuth = b64encode(b"QT8txxxxxxxx:n76mxxxxxxxxx").decode("ascii")
headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' %  appAuth  }
url = "http://demo.skubana.com?grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=demo.skubana.com/appstore&code=LCqYHU&cid=Y29tcGFueUlkMTI0MDYw"

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers,json={})

print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Please include the content you do get. While the [documentation](https://documentation.skubana.com/) does (strangly) have you send a POST no mention is made of the content type or post body, so drop the `json={}` part.

Comment: That documentation is shockingly under-specified and confusing. I see that there is a *2. Add the request path: `/oauth/token`* that's not reflected in the Sample URL, but is probably crucial. I'd  try `http://demo.skubana.com/oauth/token?...` next.

Comment: And indeed, posting to `/` gives you a login page, but posting to `/oauth/token` gives me a 401 error, telling me my credentials are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The [supplied API documentation for Skubana](https://documentation.skubana.com/) is, in my opinion, shockingly under-specified.

What you may have missed is this part:

> 2. Add the request path: /oauth/token

which, to be fair, is not reflected in their 'sample URL':

> Sample Url: `https://blah.skubana.com?grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=redirect.com/callback&code=ABCDE&cid=ABCD1234`

When you change your URL to include that path, I get a 401 Unauthorized response instead:

```
>>> url = "http://demo.skubana.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=demo.skubana.com/appstore&code=LCqYHU&cid=Y29tcGFueUlkMTI0MDYw"
>>> r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
>>> r.status_code
401
```

This too, incidentally, also involves a redirect from POST to GET. But I strongly suspect that *with the right credentials* (which I don't have) you'd actually get your token.

When you post to `https://demo.skubana.com`, you are *redirected*, first to the same URL to make a GET request, with:

```
Location: https://demo.skubana.com/?grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=demo.skubana.com/appstore&code=LCqYHU&cid=Y29tcGFueUlkMTI0MDYw
```

then on to your dashboard:

```
Location: /work/dashboard
```

and finally to the login page:

```
Location: https://demo.skubana.com/login
```

All this is recorded in the `r.history` list:

```
>>> r.history
[<Response [302]>, <Response [302]>, <Response [302]>]
```

Note that you *don't have to set `json={}`*, just use:

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

The requests library can take care of the Base64 encoding for you as that's just [part of the Basic Authentication scheme](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication), just pass in the YOUR_APP_KEY and YOUR_APP_SECRET values as *username and password*:

```
YOUR_APP_KEY = "QT8txxxxxxxx"
YOUR_APP_SECRET = "n76mxxxxxxxxx"

url = "http://demo.skubana.com/oauth/token"
parameters = {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "redirect_uri": "demo.skubana.com/appstore",
    "code": "LCqYHU",
    "cid": "Y29tcGFueUlkMTI0MDYw",
}

r = requests.post(url, params=parameters, auth=(YOUR_APP_KEY, YOUR_APP_SECRET))
```

Finally, given the redirect and *complete lack of POST parameters*, I strongly suspect that a GET request works just as well:

```
r = requests.get(url, params=parameters, auth=(YOUR_APP_KEY, YOUR_APP_SECRET))
```

This just bypasses the POST -> GET redirect.

Normally, a OAuth2 request for a token like this would post the parameters *in the POST body*, so do also try:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=parameters, auth=(YOUR_APP_KEY, YOUR_APP_SECRET))
```

if the `params=parameters` options don't get you your token, still.